# how do I upgrade from Rails 2 to Rails 3 without freezing code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rails-3-upgrade

I am upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3.  What I did was did a clone of the original app and began the upgrade process.

Unfortunately, I needed to continue to use and make refinements to Rails 2, so there have been changes in the code.

I am not done with the Rails 3 upgrade from the original code: do I need to freeze my current Rails 2 and then start-over, or is there a way I can get my original up to Rails 3 and then take only the changes made in the original and push them into the new upgrade?

Comment: What do you mean by saying "clone"? Did you make a branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose git for this kind of work, it is a beautiful tool for that.

First you can init  your source tree as a git repository, if you did not have it in git repo. If you already have it in git you can skip these steps and jump to branch creating.

```
git init .
```

Add the source files with `git add` and commit it w/ `git commit`.

Now you have a working Rails 2 app in git, create your upgrade branch for your Rails 3 modifications:

```
git checkout -b rails-3
```

Here you can modify your code to work with Rails 3. If you ever need to modify the Rails 2 part, simply checkout to the master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

Do the work, commit the modifications and then go back to Rails 3 branch and rebase:

```
git checkout rails-3 && git rebase master
```

After you're done and have a working Rails 3 app, go back and merge the changes:

```
git checkout master && git merge rails-3
```

Comment: `git` really does make this a fairly straightforward thing, especially when managing parallel trunks.

Comment: yes, thanks, I am on git, but I wasn't sure about the rest of it, thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry if this is a dumb question but....do I stay in the same project directory as my Rails 2 app, but by doing git checkout -b rails-3, continue to work there and it will be part of the branch?

Comment: Is it possible to merge two separate checkouts that have been in separate directories, one rails 2 and one rails-3?

Comment: I would cherry-pick them into the actual branch. `git cherry-pick commitid`

Comment: And yes, you should stay in your Rails app directory. I feel something strange here. Are you working on your production code?